Lyapunov stability in a one-sided neighborhood?
Consider a switching system
$$ \dot x = 
{ - x, \quad {\rm{if}}\quad x \ge 0} $$
$$
\dot x = 
{v \left( t \right), {\rm{ if}}\quad x < 0}
$$
where $ v(t) $ is bounded but indefinite (can be positive or negative)
Consider a Lyapunov function
$$
V = \frac{1}{2}{x^2}
$$
Derivative obviously:
$$
\dot V =  - {x^2}, \quad {\rm{if}}\quad x \ge 0
$$
$$
\dot V =   {v(t) \cdot x} \left( t \right), {\rm{ if}}\quad x < 0
$$
Can we talk about Lyapunov stability and negative definiteness in the domain $x \ge 0$ ?
All the textbooks I've searched only talk about some neighborhood around the equilibrium position. And here we have a one-sided neighborhood.
I would be very grateful for clarification of terminology. And maybe there are some known examples?

Practical sense of the example: we have a robot that has to reach an equilibrium position. After reaching (with very high accuracy) the equilibrium position, the control law is switched. Therefore, we are only interested in the domain $x \ge 0$. After that, we have a completely different control law. So we are not interested in what will happen in x < 0. From a practical point of view, it is quite obvious that the robot will reach the equilibrium position.


I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Do you want to know whether any solution $x$ with $x(0)>0$ will converge to the equilibrium? Or whether it will eventually be in $(-\infty,0]$? Or whether for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find some $\delta>0$ such that if $x(0)\in(-\infty,\delta)$, then $x(t)\in(-\infty,\varepsilon)$ for all $t\geq0$? Or maybe something entirely different?

As ridiculous as it is, all of these questions. But the most important question is whether the term Lyapunov stability, asymptotic stability in the domain $ x \geq 0 $, can be applied here at all?

@Tag I think you are mixing up that for $x(0)>0$ then $x(t)$ converges to $0$ (it will be a linear system, you can find an expression for the solution) with the notion of Lyapunov stability.

@jDAQ I purposely chose the simplest example. Here, of course, it is obvious that we will converge to a position of equilibrium. But it is possible to make a nonlinear system with the same question. I am interested in term Lyapunov stability for a one-sided neighborhood (such a domain). I have not found any examples.

Is it the simplest though? Why do you need the indefinite and time-varying $v(t)$? Would $\dot{x}(t) = -x(t)^2$ be ok for your question on "Lyapunov stability in a one-sided neighborhood" ?

@jDAQ I tried to explain in a "practical" example. This question arose because of the switching control law. I think you're right, because we only consider $x \geq 0$. But in all the examples I could find, a two-sided neighborhood is considered.

Since you have a switching control law $ \dot{x} = \begin{cases}
f_{1}(x) & \text{if } x < 0 \
f_{2}(x) & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases} $, why not construct a switching domain Lyapunov function? For example, $ V(x) = \int_{0}^{x} {f_{1}(z) \cdot \theta(-z) + f_{2}(z) \cdot \theta(z)} ; dz $, where $ \theta(z) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < 0 \
1 & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases} $.

@XegaXam As far as I understand, your proposed Lyapunov function is zero at $x<0$. That is, there are no other points to the left of the equilibrium point. This violates the Lyapunov definition of stability, in which the equilibrium point must be contained within the neighborhood.

@Tag Actually, I was trying to imagine the switching domain Lyapunov function for $ \dot{x} = - x^3 $ if $ x < 0 $ and $ \dot{x} = - x $ if $ x \geq 0 $. I'm unsure if it will work for your case, but the Lyapunov function I imagined looks like
$$ V(x) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} x^{4} \theta(-x)}{x < 0} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} x^{2} \theta(x)}{x \geq 0} > 0 ; \forall ; x \neq 0 $$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

@XegaXam Your system is stable (even asymptotically) in the classical Lyapunov sense. Therefore, there is no problem in using even an usual Lyapunov function of type like $V=\frac{1}{2} x^2$ My question was: what if for $x<0$ our system is unstable (here we seem to apply Chetaev's theorem). But we know for sure that at $x \ge 0$ all of our trajectories are not only stable, but will even converge to an equilibrium position.

@Tag I see. So the system actually behaves almost similarly to $\dot{x} = - x^{2}$. The solution trajectories will asymptotically converge to zero from any positive initial value $x(0) > 0$. However, if any unforeseen energy disturbs the system and causes $x(t) < 0$, then the system will blow up.
Now, the question is: What does Lyapunov's theorem tell us about the equilibrium point $x = 0$ in such a system? If we follow the definition of stability, we can ask, "Will the solution trajectories always be bounded, starting from any bounded initial state in the neighborhood of $x = 0$?"
